# Windows 10: Purpose of "Network" toggle in the Action Centre

Tags: windows-10, action-center

When I open my action centre, I have tile toggles for both Network and WiFi, and I can't tell the difference between them. I can't even tell what the purpose of Network is.

[image]

If I long click Wifi, then click the option that comes up ("Go to Settings"), it opens the Settings app to the WiFi page (as expected).

If I long click Network, and click the option that comes up ("Open Network"), it acts as though I clicked the WiFi icon in the task-bar (it shows a list of available access points). It does the same thing though if I just click Network instead of long clicking.

What is the purpose of the Network tile? It seems to have the same functionality as the WiFi icon in the task-bar, and unlike all the other Action Centre tiles (save for "All Settings"), doesn't act as a toggle; it's always off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you used an Ethernet cable to attach to the network, that would indicate a connection just like the WiFi one does.

It doesn't do anything because Windows does not detect a connection. If it were connected, you would have options to choose from.

You can adjust those tile settings at `Settings > System > Notifications & actions`.

Comment: Ah. Haven't used an Ethernet cable. In forever. Didn't even think of that. Thanks.